# Need JQuery help selecting an array of table rows (tr)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is the code snippet: http://jsbin.com/ekupa3/2/edit

I need to return the table rows (tr) that don't have a tag of 'test2'.
the output should be an array of table rows (tr).

I spent a couple hours trying every JQuery technique I knew and I will bow to the experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newTag = 'test2',
    $tr = $('tr').filter(function() {
        return $(this).html().indexOf('>' + newTag + '</a>') == -1;
    });
```

`$tr` will be a jQuery element array containing all `tr` not containing the tag `test2`.  I included parts of the HTML in the `indexOf` check in case there was another tag called "another-test2" or the like.

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/6QbEG/1/)

Comment: this works great.  It's a little less eloquent than i'd like but I'm not sure there is any other way.

Answer (score 3):

```
var newTag = 'test2';
var rows_without_newTag = $("table tr").not(":contains(" + newTag + ")");
```

[Created an edit of the OP's JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ekupa3/4/) w/ some example usage for posterity's sake.